# How to make my code do the round a correct calculation?

Tags: c

I use the DEV C++."c" can not correctly calculate

I type r=1.5h=3,but the results are 0.00

```
float r,h,c,s1,pai;
    pai=3.14;
    scanf("r=%fh=%f",&r,&h);
    c=2.0*pai*r;
    s1=pai*r*r;
    printf("c=%6.2f\ns1=%6.2f",&c,&s1);
    return 0;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYx7S.png)

Comment: what is your expected result?

Comment: Your value of `pai` will give you a short circumference.

Comment: Without your given input and printed result besides the expected result we cannot tell much.

Comment: You do not verify that you got correct return value from `scanf`. How would you know if your data was read properly?

Comment: Please do not add screenshots of plain text. You can easily copy&paste the text into your question body.

Comment: @Gerhardh I got it.Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Besides other things, here

```
printf("c=%6.2f\ns1=%6.2f",&c,&s1);
//                         ^  ^
```

The code is trying to print the **addresses** of the two `float` variables (the result beeing undefined behavior, due to the wrong format specifier), not the variables themselves.

Just remove remove the `&`.

```
printf("c=%6.2f\ns1=%6.2f", c, s1);
```

It would also be better to check the return value of `scanf`, to be sure that the extraction of those values actually succeeded.

Comment: I just started learning programming. I will try to learn how to use "&".You're my hero for the day. Thank you!

Comment: @yax First lesson: Enable all compiler warnings. Normally your compiler should tell you that you have a mismatch in format specifier and provided types.

Comment: I think I have enabled it. When I make other mistakes,it can remind me.